# How to import foreign key constraints to InnoDB tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, myisam

I have my local MySQL database set to use the InnoDB engine by default. The database holds about 30 tables, all InnoDB.

However, when I ran the migrations to create the same database on a remote server, it had MyISAM as the default, and it created all the tables in MyISAM.

Since MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys the way InnoDB does, they were all lost in the process. Now I've changed all the tables on the remote server to InnoDB manually.

What is the best/quickest way to import just the foreign key constraints from the local to the remote database now? I can go one table at a time and add them all, but I was wondering if there's a better way.

Dumping the remote database and then rebuilding it is not an option at this point.

Comment: Two options come to my mind: 1. Query the information_schema to build the `ALTER TABLE` statements. 2. Use something like `mysqldump --no-data` and grep for the table name and the foreign key constraint and build the statements in a bash script or something. First option is probably easier.

Comment: @fancyPants In the end I just used the export option in phpMyAdmin, selected "structure only", and at the bottom of the file all the constraints are neatly listed.

Comment: Good to hear :)

Comment: I edited your use of "relation" and replaced it with "foreign key constraint." Please understand that "relation" means a set of tuples, in other words a table, not a foreign key. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database)

Comment: How did you do the migration?  mysqldump would have captured the Engine of each table and the load would have honored that, even if the "default" were MyISAM.